# Wget generating files instead of HTMLs

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, html, wget, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to download a whole website for viewing offline using

```
wget --mirror -p --convert-links https://www.example.com
```

but after it finishes, some of the HTML documents have no extension. Windows simply states that their file type is `File`. I can change them into HTML documents by adding `.html` to the file names (I used `ren *.* *.html` in command prompt), but then the links do not work correctly. How do I get wget to download the HTML documents as HTMLs OR automatically restructure the links to work with the new files? There are over 10,000 individual HTML files so I do not want to do it manually.

I am running Windows 10 and am using Ubuntu 18.04 terminal through Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out. I had to add the option `-E`, or `--html-extension`, in order to get it to force the files to be `.html` files, making the whole string:

```
wget --mirror -p --convert-links -E https://www.example.com
```